# Is there an Eclipse Pydev setting or something in my Python get request preventing me from connecting with a host?

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, python-requests, pydev

I am trying to read data from an ESA server in a PyDev Eclipse 3.8.1 Environment using Python 3.5.3. An example of a product link is given here:

"[https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('c7208694-dedb-4f47-96c0-c8fb03512ff5')](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('c5dc59f0-b041-4f76-a685-49be63491270'))

You will need authentication credentials to access the website.

In my Eclipse environment I have manually added in proxy settings by going to Windows-> General -> Network Connections. Authentication is not required for the proxy.

To get the content of the webpage, I use a Python get request to send my query as below:

```
url = r"https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('c5dc59f0-b041-4f76-a685-49be63491270')"

r = requests.get(url, verify=False, proxies=proxies, auth=auth)
```

I need the `verify=False` to disable the certificate check and `proxies` is a dictionary storing the proxy addresses with the relevant port. Server credentials are given with `auth` which is a tuple of a username and password.

When I send the request to the server, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 301, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fecf00acbe0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='scihub.copernicus.eu', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dhus/odata/v1/Products('c5dc59f0-b041-4f76-a685-49be63491270') (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fecf00acbe0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download_lib2/download_lib/scihub/download.py", line 325, in <module>
    download_url(dl_link, auth, temp_dir)
  File "download_lib2/download_lib/scihub/download.py", line 153, in download_url
    online = check_url_online(url_to_download, auth)
  File "download_lib2/download_lib/scihub/download.py", line 51, in check_url_online
    r = requests.get(url, verify=False, proxies=proxies, auth=auth)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='scihub.copernicus.eu', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dhus/odata/v1/Products('c5dc59f0-b041-4f76-a685-49be63491270') (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fecf00acbe0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
```

I have tried the same request outside of Eclipse, in IDLE, and I am able to successfully connect and read the content. Is there something wrong with my current Eclipse/PyDev environment that will not allow me to send a get request?

Why is Python not able to connect? I am able to send get requests to this and other websites using other projects in Eclipse (e.g. https://podaac-opendap.jpl.nasa.gov/opendap/allData/oscar/preview/L4/oscar_third_deg/) with no problem whatsoever.

Edit: Added in versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `socks` timeout indicates that your problem is actually the connection to your proxy as opposed to the ESA server. Additionally, I believe the proxy settings in Eclipse are only used for plugins/software updates and not by any code you write.

As an initial step, check your [proxy dictionary](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) keys are correct and verify your proxy URLS if you can.

You mention you have other Eclipse projects that can access the internet; it's worth checking what proxy settings they implement and seeing if there are any discrepancies with your current setup.